# Order statistics of Brownian motions

Tags: brownian-motion

I've been struggling with proving a conjecture concerning order statistics of Brownian motions for a while. The conjecture I'm looking to prove is the following: (I have run Monte Carlo simulations that confirm the conjecture.)

Let $(q_1(t), …, q_n(t))$ be a vector of independent Brownian motions with $q_i(0) = 0$ for all $i$. Let $T > 0$. Each $q_i$ represents an object in a game, and each of $J < n$ players in the game can pick exactly one object $i$ at any time $t \in [0, T]$. Whenever a player picks an object, he picks the one that currently has the highest value amongst those that have not been picked before. A player's payoff is the value of the object at the time he picks it. Let $x_j(t_j; t_1, …, t_{j-1})$ denote the expected payoff (expectation taken at time 0) from picking at time $t_j$, given that players $1, …, j-1$ will pick at times $t_1, …, t_{j-1}$. I want to show that $x_j(t_j; t_1, …, t_{j-1})$ is decreasing in $t_1, …, t_{j-1}$.

I will need this for an economic theory paper I'm writing, and would be very grateful for any help!

Some things that I already thought through:

- I have already shown that $x_j(t_j; t_1, …, t_{j-1})$ is increasing in $t$ and jointly continuous in all arguments.
- The case $j=2$ is quite tractable, and for the case $j = 3$ I have the intuition on how to prove it. That intuition, however, doesn't extend to the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy of the other $n-1$ players can be viewed as a single adversary trying to minimize the payoff of the $n$th player. Picking the highest unpicked object is optimal for that adversary by coupling.

If $t_{i-1} \le t_i' \lt t_i$ then picking at time $t_i'$ instead of $t_i$ does an imperfect job of choosing the unpicked object which will be highest at time $t_i$. You can view picking at $t_i'$ as sometimes playing optimally at time $t_i$, and sometimes choosing a lower object at time $t_i$.

If you want to consider decreasing $t_i'$ past $t_{i-1}$ then you can view this as decreasing $t_i'$ to $t_{i-1}$, then replacing $t_{i-1}$ with a smaller $t_{i-1}'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, either I misunderstand your reply, or you misunderstood my question. I'm interested the payoff to player $j$ holding fixed $t_j$, but varying $t_1, …, t_{j-1}$.  (I'm only interested in the case $t_1\leq…\leq t_j$.) In case I misunderstood your reply, then it's probably the first two lines.

Comment: @Sandro: I assumed $j=n$ because later players don't affect player $j$ so we might as well assume player $j$ is the last player. What don't you understand about the first two lines of my answer?

Comment: You use $i$ and $j$ interchangeably, right? I guess the stumbling block is the coupling (of I know the definition, but don't have experience with). Also, I'm not sure whether $j=n$ is w.l.o.g. (but that might be because I don't yet quite understand your proof.) If $j=n$ then any gain to the adversary is a loss to player $j$. If $j<n$, then a gain to the adversary can also be due to him picking the player who will be ranked second-to-worst rather than worst at $t_j$, which will not decrease player $j$'s payoff.

Comment: @Sandro: No, I don't use $i$ and $j$ interchangeably. $i$ is an index of an opponent's choice.

Comment: Could you say which BMs you couple, and what coupling you choose?

Comment: @Sandro: Continue all Brownian motions with one (inductively, some subset) translated. If you translate one BM up by removing a lower BM instead of the highest, then all of your choices at the next removal point are translations of the possibilities if you had removed the highest.

Comment: Wow, I finally got it!:) Thanks! Douglas Zare is your real name? Then I can appropriately credit you in a footnote. (My Advisor, Al Roth, thinks the paper will be published well.)

Comment: @Sandro: I'm happy to have helped. Yes, this is my real name.

Comment: I just noted a mistake in my proof that $x_j(t_j;t_1, …, t_{j-1})$ is jointly continuous in all arguments. I think what I'm missing might be a standard argument. I take a sequence $(s_1^n, …, s_j^n)$ that converges to $(t_1, …, t_j)$, and try to show that $x_j(s_1^n, …, s_j^n) - x_j(t_1, …, t_j)$ converges to 0. So I condition the expectation on the left on $q(t_1), … , q(t_j)$ (law of it. exp.). By continuity of the Brownian paths, I then get pointwise convergence. However, I'm lacking a dominating function, so I can't apply Lebesgue's theorem. Any ideas for a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @Sandro: I think a similar coupling argument works, showing not just continuity but Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: Would you mind outlining the proof you have in mind a bit more? What do you use the coupling for? To estimate the distance to the limit for each $n$? How does the coupling imply Lipschitz continuity? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sandro: Lipschitz continuity should fail when the times are close to $0$, but other than that I think it should work, though I haven't written out the details. One idea is to compare $x$ at one set of times with $x$ at another set in which all of the times are a little later (not just close). If these have to be close, then you can compare $x$ at close points by comparing each with the coordinatewise maximum. Next, to compare $x$ at a point $T$ with $x$ at a point $T'$ with all times slightly greater, note that at $T'$ you can use the strategy of optimizing wrt what you knew at $T$,

Comment: and you only have slightly more information at $T'$. So, for example, if you choose at time $1.01$ the particle that was greatest at time $1.00$, this will rarely lead to a significantly different outcome. In case you choose a different particle, use coupling to switch the motions.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that basically all I needed was the Lebesgue Vitali theorem that provides the right generalization of the dominated convergence theorem, so I can get from the a.s.-convergence, which quite obviously holds, to convergence in expectation. In any case, thanks a lot for your help!